# Area between three curves involves tangent line

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be the region enclosed by the $x$-axis, the curve $y=x^{2}$, and the tangent to the curve at $x=a$, where $a>0$. If the area of $R$ is $\frac{2}{3}$, then the value of $a$ is?

Is there any clue for the tangent equation and how's the integral equation will be?

Thanks!

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far? And in most calculus curricula, you would need to understand how to get the equation of the tangent line long before you start on areas and integration. What calculus have you learned so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent at $(a, a^2)$ has equation $ y-a^2=2a(x-a)  $So the $x$-intercept is $\frac a2 $

$$A = \int_0^{\frac a2} x^2 dx+ \int_{\frac a2}^a( x^2 -(2ax-a^2)) \;dx   $$

Answer (score 0):

Hints :

tangent is passing through $(a,a^2)$ where its slope would be $\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=a}}$

Area of R would be the difference between the region of curve and the region of tangent line enclosed by the x-axis. (from $0$ to $a$)